# Prevent shell from saving attribute in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have an attribute on a model that I don't want another developer to be able to go into the Django shell and change. Anyone know how to do this? I tried overwriting the save method on that model but I can't determine if that attribute has been changed.

Comment: How can a _user_ go into the Django shell?

Comment: You're right a 'user' can't. I should have said another developer

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are trying to accomplish? Another developer can also undo your method by modifying your code.

Comment: If someone has access to django shell, has also access to database configuration, so he can make way around your prevention. Unless you will make your own shell, i think it's not possible, django doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured out how to accomplish this. Another developer could always change the code but this raises an error saying that's not what they're supposed to do.

```
class myModel(models.Model):


    uuid = UUIDField('UUID', primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    model_type = models.ForeignKey(ModelType)

    # override the Press model __init__ method to store initial press_type
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(myModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__model_type = self.model_type

    # override the save method to prevent updates to press_type
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # raise an exception if press_type was changed since initialized
        if self.pk and self.__model_type != self.model_type:
            raise Exception('The model_type field cannot be changed once set.')

        super(myModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```